# iOS Autolayout constants issues which cause the UIView not occupy the whole width in iPad

Tags: ios, autolayout

Here is the screenshot of my ViewController in my Storyboard. As you see, there is a UITableView inside.

[image]

And the autolayout setting is like this:

[image]

There is only one setting for "wAny hAny". That means the layout should be the same in iPhone and iPad. Unfortunately it's not. It's fine in iPhone. But in iPad, the result is like this:

[image]

The tableview is not taking the whole width of the UIView. Why? Can anybody suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck constrain to margins, and set all constraint values zero.